# Windows XP Domain password

Tags: passwords, domain, workgroup

I changed the computer properties so that it doesn't log onto a domain anymore, but unfortunately I restarted the computer before I added a new user. 
Now, I am faced with a logon screen (not the welcome screen), and I know one of the usernames and the password on the old domain. I also have no idea what the Administrator password is on the local computer.

I am unable to log back onto the original domain (where I have administrator privileges), because the local login screen does not present any options for specifying the domain. I also can't seem to change it back to a domain computer, since I have to login first (which I can't do). How would I go either getting this machine to log back onto a domain.

Rebooting in safe mode still asked me to login, so that's no help..

Answer (score 0):

When you disjoin a computer from a domain, you can only login to local accounts. If you still have a username and password from a local account, you should be able to bring the pc back into the domain.

If you can't however, the only alternative is to reinstall windows.

You can try entering [pcname]\Administrator without any password or [domain]\username with the password you know. The domain one will likely not be accepted if you properly disjoined the domain as there is a thrust issue now, but you can still try that. You can also try [pcname]\username from the domain and hope that the user is still cached locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) to reset the local administrator account's password so you can log in. The web site includes CD images that you can boot from and launch the tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could try ophcrack

Or, way faster:

1. boot with a live linux from stick
2. Locate `sethc.exe` (google first what  its path is in xp)
3. Locate `cmd.exe` and copy it
4. backup `sethc.exe` and replace the original with the copy of `cmd.exe` (rename it)
5. Shut down and boot with windows
6. On logonscreen, press five times SHIFT
7. Cmd will pop up
8. Enter `control userpasswords2`

Create a local account